# Android Fatal: Error java.lang.IllegalStateException on button click when creating Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to connect to a server I'm running my computer through my phone. Every time I click the connect button it gives me the java.lang.IllegalStateException. When the connect button is clicked it creates a socket that's supposed to connect to the server on my computer. 
Here's the error

```
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     ... 11 more
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at com.example.socketconnection.Singleton.connect(Singleton.java:44)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     at com.example.socketconnection.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:47)
08-21 23:45:26.427: E/AndroidRuntime(4986):     ... 14 more
```

Here's the code for MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.socketconnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private TextView errorMessageField;
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        errorMessageField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorMessageText);
        errorMessageField.setKeyListener(null);
        initSingleton();
    }

    protected void initSingleton()
    {
        Singleton.initSingleton();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

   public void connect(View view)
   {
       EditText userNameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
       EditText passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
       String userName = userNameField.getText().toString();
       String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
       userNameField.setText("");
       passwordField.setText("");
       errorMessageField.setText("");
       String member = Singleton.getInstance().connect(userName, password);
       if(member.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
       {
           errorMessageField.setText("");
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserList.class);
           intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, userName);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
       else if(member.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
       {
           errorMessageField.setText("Invalid User Name/Password");
       }
       else
       {
           errorMessageField.setText("Invalid User Name/Password");
       }
   }

}
```

Code for Singleton.java

```
package com.example.socketconnection;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Singleton 
{
    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream input;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private boolean logged;
    private static Singleton instance;
    private String information;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
            return instance;
    }

    public static void initSingleton()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
    }

    public String connect(String userName, String password)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;

        try
        {
            this.socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.79"), 9000);
            this.input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            this.output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            output.writeUTF("login");
            output.flush();
            output.writeUTF(userName);
            output.flush();
            output.writeUTF(password);
            output.flush();
            this.information = input.readUTF();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            this.information = "Cannot connect to Server";
        }

        return information;
    }

    public void setLogged(boolean logged)
    {
        this.logged = logged;
    }

    public Socket getSocket()
    {
        return socket;
    }

    public DataInputStream getInput()
    {
        return input;
    }

    public DataOutputStream getOutput()
    {
        return output;
    }

    public boolean getLogged()
    {
        return logged;
    }
}
```

Code for UserList.java

```
package com.example.socketconnection;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class UserList extends Activity 
{

    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream input;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private String userName;
    private String [] users;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        userName = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);



        ListView userList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.userList);
        users = new String[0];
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, users);
        userList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        socket = Singleton.getInstance().getSocket();
        input = Singleton.getInstance().getInput();
        output = Singleton.getInstance().getOutput();
        Runnable task = new UpdateTask(listAdapter);
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
    }

    class UpdateTask implements Runnable
    {
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private boolean logged = true;

        public UpdateTask(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter)
        {
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        public void loggedOut(boolean logged)
        {
            this.logged = logged;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            { 
                while(logged)
                {
                    if(input.available() > 0)
                    {
                        String message = input.readUTF();
                        if(!message.equalsIgnoreCase("chat"))
                        {
                           users = getList(message);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }  
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            }    
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
            }
        }
        public String[] getList(String message)
        {
            String line = message;
            String[] list;
            String[] split;
            int counter = 0;

            String temp = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1);
            split = temp.split(", ");
            if(split.length == 1)
            {
                list = new String[0];
            }
            else
            {
                list = new String[split.length - 1];
                for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
                {
                    if(!split[i].equalsIgnoreCase(userName))
                    {
                        list[counter] = split[i];
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it is  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. You are doing network operation in main thread. Create AsyncTask and do it in the background method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just block the main applocation thread like that, with your `Singleton.connect` invoke.

Instead, take advantage of [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can call `connect` safely from inside the context of `doInBackground` :-) The code which relies on your result can then be done **safely in the context of the main application thread** in `onPostExecute`.